# New-LocalUser/LocalGroup Path?

Tags: powershell

My boss gave me a task to do in PowerShell, he wanted me to write a script.

The script should make a folder and ask for foldername then make 2 groups with read write, then make 2 users, one in each group and ask what user should be in what group. And after that, make rights for the groups to the folders.

I already have the first part in place, make a folder and make it ask for what name:

```
$foldername1 = read-host -Prompt 'input folder name'
new-item "c:\temp\$foldername1" -type Directory
```

The problem is when I'm making groups and users. There is no path?
The syntax reads:

```
New-LocalUser [-Name] <String> [-AccountExpires <DateTime>] [-AccountNeverExpires] [-Confirm] [-Description <String>] [-Disabl
ed] [-FullName <String>] -NoPassword [-UserMayNotChangePassword] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]
```

And the same for `new-localgroup`

How do I choose the path for the user/group I am making?

I'm new to Powershell and new in my internship.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a `path` for a `local user`.

You will see local user using either PowerShell or the GUI: `Start => Computer Management => System Tools => Local Users and Groups`

Comment: yes i found out there is no path for it.

i am asking is there a way to make a user and put it in a folder i choose?

Comment: You cannot put a user in a folder. You can put users in groups or groups in groups and you can set permissions for users and / and or groups on folders.

Answer (score 0):

This sample might be aligned with what you're looking for.

```
$foldername1 = read-host -Prompt 'input folder name'
new-item "c:\temp\$foldername1" -type Directory
$group1 = read-host -Prompt 'input first group name'
$group2 = read-host -Prompt 'input second group name'
New-LocalGroup -Name $group1
New-LocalGroup -Name $group2
$user1 = read-host -Prompt 'input first user name'
$user2 = read-host -Prompt 'input second user name'
New-LocalUser -Name $user1
New-LocalUser -Name $user2
$addGroup1 = read-host "Which user in" $group1
if ($addGroup1 -match $user1)
{
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $group1 -Member $user1
}
if ($addGroup1 -match $user2)
{
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $group1 -Member $user2
}
$addGroup2 = read-host  "which user in" $group2
if ($addGroup2 -match $user1)
{
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $group2 -Member $user1
}
if ($addGroup2 -match $user2)
{
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $group2 -Member $user2
}
write-host "Current members in" $group1 $group2
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $group1
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $group2


$rule1 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule 
("$group1","ReadAndExecute","Allow")
$rule2 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule 
("$group2","ReadAndExecute","Allow")
$acl = get-acl "c:\temp\$foldername1"
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule1)
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule2)
$acl | select -ExpandProperty access
```

Comment: Obviously needs some more work for putting the right user in the right group and so on, but I believe it can get you started at least.

Comment: thanks i must say. the code looks great. BUT i am sorry to say this but what i need is for the users and the groups to be in the set $foldername1. (edit) i found out you can't put users in folders

Comment: I fail to understand what you need at this point. So you're creating 2 groups with 1 user each, but both groups will have Read/Write access to the same folder? If you could explain some more about what you're trying to achieve I might be able to help further.

Comment: sorry for not being clear in my English, its not my first language. and yes that is what i need, the 2 groups should both have read/write accesse to the same folder (dont ask why) but i also need for the code to ask for what user should be in what group

Comment: So this code-sample works, but I would encourage you to modify it. I'm sure there are easier ways to go about it.

Comment: yes it works like i want it to, but comes with 2 errors… New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Security.AccessCont
rol.FileSystemAccessRule.
At line:13 char:9... get-acl : Cannot find path 'Test1' because it does not exist.
At line:15 char:8
+ $acl = get-acl $foldername1... i dont get that it can't find the $foldername (called it test1) i can find the folder but the code can't

Comment: You will need get-acl "c:\temp\$foldername1". 
get-acl $foldername1 only gets the folder, not the filepath.